# Express endpoint not getting called

Tags: node.js, express

An endpoint works fine if added directly to my `server.js` file:

```
app.post('/test', function(req,res) {
  res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
});
```

but in an attempt to refactor the app I include a file called `api.js` from `server.js` like this:

```
var routesApi = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/v1', routesApi);
```

and it looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function() {   
  router.post('/test', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
  });

  return router;
}
```

but if I try and hit this end point the req "stalls" as there is no response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you exported your router, you need to invoke `routesApi` when adding it to the middleware stack via `.use()`. This is how that might look like

```
app.use('/v1', routesApi());
```

Though you can avoid this altogether by changing your api.js to look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/test', function(req, res){
  res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and the code for the server can stay the same since now, you're exporting an instance of the Router module.

Answer (score -1):

you have define global variable for app and may use like this:

> api.js

```
exports.allRoutes=function() {

var version1="v1";

app.post('/'+version1+'/test', function(req, res){
res.status(200).send({"message" : "OK"});
});

}
```

> app.js

```
global.app = express();

var all_routes = require('./server/routes/api');

all_routes.allRoutes();  

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(req,res){           
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));     
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure globals is the answer!